# Filtrar datos por un rango de fechas, no filtra nada por mal comparación entre fechas como parametros. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Mi sentencia es muy simple quiero obtener los datos aquellos que cumplan entre dos fechas como parametros "fechainicial" y "fechafinal", muy conocido por todos. Pero al momento de ejecutar la sentencia, que lo hace bien, me filtra algunas veces bien o otras veces no.

Hay ejecuciones de la misma que deberian filtrarse los datos. La filtracion lo hago con la funcion **between** que es para comparar entre datos y tambien probe con la manera tradicional **(where fecha >= fechainicio and fecha <= fechafinal)** pero en ambas la filtracion sale y en otras me sigue saliendo vacio, cosa que esta mal.
Paso el codigo:
con la funcion tradicional:

```
select v.NroFactura,date_format(v.FechaVenta, '%d/%m/%Y') as Fecha,p.descripcion,d.Precio,d.Cantidad,(d.Precio*d.Cantidad) as SubTotal from ventas as v INNER JOIN detallesventas as d on v.idventa=d.idventa INNER JOIN productos as p on p.idproducto=d.idproducto where date_format(date(FechaVenta),'%d/%m/%Y') >= '20/02/2019' and date_format(date(FechaVenta),'%d/%m/%Y') <= '28/02/2019' and d.activo=1 and p.activo=1 and v.activo=1 order by date_format(v.FechaVenta, '%d/%m/%Y')desc,v.NroFactura;
```

con la funcion between:

```
select v.NroFactura,date_format(v.FechaVenta, '%d/%m/%Y') as Fecha,p.descripcion,d.Precio,d.Cantidad,(d.Precio*d.Cantidad) as SubTotal from ventas as v INNER JOIN detallesventas as d on v.idventa=d.idventa INNER JOIN productos as p on p.idproducto=d.idproducto where date_format(date(FechaVenta),'%d/%m/%Y') between '20/02/2019' and '28/02/2019' and d.activo=1 and p.activo=1 and v.activo=1 order by date_format(v.FechaVenta, '%d/%m/%Y')desc,v.NroFactura;
```

el tipo de dato que uso para las fechas es de datetime. Convierto el formato dd/mm/YYYY y luego solo pido que me devuelva la fecha sin hora (date).

He visto en este foro y en otros que es conveniente agregar las horas, que es por eso se filtran mal para los que usan el tipo de dato datetime. Que para mi no seria una relevancia para este caso puesto que especifico que solo me devuelva sola fecha con la funcion DATE. Sin embargo lo probe igual para saber si resolvia mi problema pero no fue asi.

Hay un detalle que me percate cuando queria hacer la filtracion por la manera tradicional. **LAS COMPARACIONES EN FECHAS TOMAN EN CUENTA LOS DIAS NADA MAS.**
Despues el mes y el año no lo toman en cuenta, osea no compara por la fecha en si, sino por dicho dia de las fechas.

Para hacer un ejemplo supongamos que tengo datos en la fecha **'21/02/2019'** entonces haciendo de la manera tradicional seria los siguiente tomando como parametros fechainicial(**'10/02/2019'**) y fechafinal(**'28/02/2019'**): **select * from tabla where fecha >= '10/02/2019' and fecha <= '28/02/2019';**
Si ejecuto esta sentencia se me filtrarían correctos los datos. Porque basándome en el pequeño detalle que me percate seria: **21/02/2019 >= 10/02/2019** lo toma **porque el DIA de la fecha es MAYOR al parametro** y lo mismo cumple la misma con el segundo parametro, cosa que no deberia ser asi. Sino de comparar en si toda la fecha (dia/mes/año). PERO AHORA si cambio las fechas de los parametros fechainicial(**'22/01/2019'**) y fechafinal(**'01/03/2019'**), en este caso la filtracion sera vacia porque basándose al detalle que me descubri: **21/02/2019 >= 22/01/2019** **ACA ES EL ERROR** deberia filtrarme los datos correctamente pero como les decia no lo hace porque **compara EN DIAS ya que 21 no es mayor o igual que 22**. Sin embargo tomando el mes y el año o mas bien ya con el mes seria lo suficiente para MYSQL lo filtre como se debe pero tal caso no es asi.

Por favor corroboren ustedes mismos el detalle que me fije en MYSQL y comenten si les da el mismo error o no.

Volviendo al caso hay un error que estoy cometiendo o no me percate de ello? falta algun dato mas para que las filtraciones se obtengan correctamente?

Espero que me puedan ayudar en esto y muchas gracias por su tiempo! Saludos

Comment: ¿Acaso tus columnas no son del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME` en la tabla? ¿Por qué entonces haces esta barbaridad: `date_format(date(FechaVenta),'%d/%m/%Y') >= '20/02/2019'` en vez de formatear la cadena así: `2019/02/20` y luego comparar simplemente de este modo: `FechaVenta >= '2019/02/20'` o usando `BETWEEN` si prefieres? ... ¿No te das cuenta que estás sacrificando toda la estructura de la base de datos, cuando deberías actuar sencillamente sobre la cadena de fecha con la que estás trabajando? Cuando trabajes con fechas siempre usa el formato inglés para cálculos y comparaciones.

Comment: Si no lo consigues, edita la pregunta enviándonos la base de datos en SQL con las propusesta de @A.Cedano, a ver qué  cómo lo podemos arreglar. Ánimo.

Comment: @A.Cedano antes que nada muchas gracias por comentar a dicho problema que tengo. Si como dije en el cuerpo de texto, para las fechas uso el tipo de dato DATETIME y porque uso esto: date_format(date(FechaVenta),'%d/%m/%Y'), simple, porque estoy programando en java y mi cliente quiere la fecha en formato dd/mm/YYYY. Es por eso que comparo con una fecha de ese formato puesto que en java tengo un componente jdatechooser y el formato que uso para extraer dicha fecha es la misma dd/mm/YYYY.

Comment: Exe pero eso no tiene nada que ver, una cosa es el formato y otra el código interno. O sea, en el código interno es mejor usar el formato `YYYYMMDD` para calcular, comparar, guardar... luego en pantalla puedes formatear para presentar los datos como el cliente los requiere. Es un error cambiar el formato de las fechas para guardarlas o para hacer cálculos, no sólo pierdes en rendimiento, sino que te expones a errores, como de hecho te está ocurriendo. Es importante que entiendas que una cosa es el formato (representación de los datos) y otra cosa son los datos en sí.

Comment: @David ok eso hare, voy a probar de la manera formato ingles como propone A.Cedano a ver que resultados salen. Saludos

Comment: Espero que no hayas cometido el error de guardar las fechas en este formato `DD/MM/YYYY` en la base de datos. Tienes que ser muy cuidadoso con eso, guardando siempre las fechas en el formato `YYYYMMDD`. Si el cliente elige una fecha en un DateChooser y la misma tiene el formato `DD/MM/YYYY` lo que tienes que hacer **en el código interno** es convertir ese valor a `YYYYMMDD` y hacer la comparación. Como comprenderás, es más simple y más seguro que formatear, reformatear, etc. El que el cliente te pida un formato no significa que en el código interno tengas que plegarte a ese requerimiento.

Comment: Perfecto @A.Cedano tenes razon, disculpa por mi obstinada forma de pensar. Muchas gracias por sus recomendaciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo estoy convirtiendo pero en la base de datos esta en su formato por defecto.

Comment: Perfecto. Entonces lo único que tendrías que hacer es convertir la cadena, y escribir la consulta sin tanto rollo de formateo. O sea, cambiar esto: `20/02/2019` a esto: `20190220`, esto `28/02/2019` a esto `20190228` y luego escribir la consulta así: `where FechaVenta BETWEEN '20190220'  AND '20190228'` evitando todo el rollo de `date_format  ... date ... '%d/%m/%Y'` en el `WHERE`, pues no es otra cosa que marear y marear las cosas.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano y David eso fue el problema, en otros formatos que no sea la que es por defecto no lo compara bien. arregle de esta forma str_to_date((str_to_date('20/02/2019','%d/%m/%Y')),'%Y-%m-%d') hago las comparaciones y los hace perfecto. Les agradezco por resolver el problema. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conviene que siempre distingas entre lo que es un formato y lo es el funcionamiento interno del código.

El hecho de que el cliente necesite fechas en el formato `DD/MM/YYYY` no significa que tengas que sacrificar todo el código a dicho formato como haces aquí por ejemplo:

```
where 
    date_format(date(FechaVenta),'%d/%m/%Y') >= '20/02/2019' and 
    date_format(date(FechaVenta),'%d/%m/%Y') <= '28/02/2019' and
```

Si en la tabla, la columna `FechaVenta` es del tipo `DATETIME` y dicho tipo de datos se almacena con el formato `YYYYMMDD`, ¿por qué hay que manipularlo en un `WHERE`, aplicándole dos funciones (`date_format` y `date`) y exponiéndose además a resultados erróneos como es el caso?

Es mucho más simple tomar el valor de la fecha que ingresa el cliente y adaptarlo a un formato idóneo para comparar. **Siempre** que trabajes con fechas usa el formato inglés para guardarlas o para hacer cálculos y para la salida muestra el resultado en el formato requerido. Son dos cosas distintas.

En resumen, toma los valores `20/02/2019` y `28/02/2019`  y pásalos a `YYYYMMDD`, luego, haz la consulta sin preocuparte por el formato en el criterio `WHERE`:

```
WHERE FechaVenta BETWEEN '20190220' and '20190228' ...
```

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**
>
> Considera el uso de consultas preparadas, para evitar riesgos de
>   *Inyección SQL*. Si los valores de fecha u otros son variables dinámicas, un usuario mal intencionado podría manipularlos agregando
>   consultas suplementarias que se ejecutarían sin ningún control,
>   produciendo daños que podrían ser gravísimos.